# TAS from POH or e6b

Tags: flight-planning, airspeed

I always calculated my TAS at any cruise altitude by

1. Using my planned cruise (pressure) altitude, temperature
2. Plug desired CAS, PA, temperature into e6b and get TAS

But I've also seen people get TAS only from the POH for cruise. And many books say that e6b is only used for TOC and that for cruise you should use the POH.

The discrepancy I see is that the POH assumes a constant power setting. But I'm assuming a constant CAS. So, in that case it seems my way should be more accurate.

What's the proper procedure that a student pilot should follow?

p.s. I fly a pa-28-181.

Comment: You’re asking about flight planning, not in-flight use, correct?

Comment: [there are many replies and comments on the identical Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/flying/comments/v7vb1d/calculating_tas/)

Comment: @StephenS yes, flight planning. Not in flight use

Comment: It doesn't matter, you'll get the same TAS either way as it's just a calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the POH with a fixed power setting is more correct, and as a student, you should absolutely do it that way.

The POH is where you get your fuel burn per hour. That, combined with GS and ETE per leg (which you’ll get from TAS and winds aloft) will give you the fuel burn per leg, which is a critical part of your flight planning.

Comment: This doesn’t make sense.  TAS is simply the actual speed the AC is moving through the air. It is calculated from indicated airspeed by accounting for the density of air at altitude.  It has nothing to do with power settings.  The POH can only display expected TAS vs power settings for a nominal engine- which is often not the case in real life.

Comment: But OP says: Noting my cruise (pressure) altitude, temp.  This leads me to believe he’s in the airplane not planning.  Maybe I interpreted wrong?

Comment: Me either.  My ASI had a temperature knob and did the E6B calculation implicitly.  But in planning where would you even get CAS from??

Comment: @Jim I suspect OP is planning to fly a fixed IAS/CAS and adjust power as needed to achieve it. My CFI disabused me of that idea when I started XC flight planning.

Comment: Ok. May be. I agree- dumb idea.  It’s coming at it bassackwards.

Comment: Why is flying a fixed CAS a bad idea? this seems counterintuitive to me. If I fly a fixed power, then the plane has no idea of the environmental factors. So I'm basically letting the plane boss me around with what speed it wants to fly at. The timing aspect of XC only works if I'm trying to achieve my CAS. Am I having a big hole somewhere?

Comment: Because to fly a fixed CAS selected on a whim you will be constantly jockeying the throttle to keep it there. You will have no idea what your performance/endurance will be.  The proper way is to use the performance charts to trade speed for fuel/endurance and arrive at a desired TAS/power combination. Then you fly that power setting and hopefully get at least the airspeed you chose.  Maybe you’ll get more! Maybe you’ll get less and you’ll know you’ll need to take action to ensure you’ll reach your destination with the required fuel reserves.  Flying CAS you’ll have no idea.

Comment: @Jonathan In short: because that’s the only way you can predict your fuel burn and therefore know if you have enough fuel to reach your destination (plus reserves). That’s kinda important.